# no results were returned by the query

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql

```
Connection con = null;
Statement stmt = null;
Statement resultStmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    // load database driver driver
    System.out.println("Database driver is: " + DataSource.getClassName());
    Class.forName(DataSource.getClassName());

    // connect to database from a given URL with a given username and password
    System.out.println("Database URL is: " + DataSource.getURL());
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(DataSource.getURL(), DataSource.getUserName(), DataSource.getPassword());

    // create an SQL statement object
    stmt = con.createStatement();

    stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO leadcustomer " + "VALUES(1, 'junwei', 'Li', 'heaven road','test@test.com')");

    String SQLStatement = "SELECT * FROM leadcustomer";
    System.out.println("Q1 SQL Statement is: " + SQLStatement);

    rs = resultStmt.executeQuery(SQLStatement);

    while (rs.next()) {
        int customerid = rs.getInt("customerid");
        String fistname = rs.getString("firstname");
        String surname = rs.getString("surname");
        String billAddress = rs.getString("billingAddress");
        String email = rs.getString("email");

        System.out.println("customerid : " + customerid);
        System.out.println("firstname : " + fistname);
        System.out.println("surname : " + surname);
        System.out.println("billingAddress : " + billAddress);
        System.out.println("email : " + email);


        System.out.println(customerid + " : " + fistname + "--" + surname + "--" + billAddress + ":" + email);
    }

    con.close();

    // extract name from first row and print

} catch (SQLException e) {
    // print details of SQL error
    // could be multiple errors chained together
    System.err.println("Error(s) occurred");
    while (e != null) {
        System.err.println("SQLException : " + e.getMessage());
        System.err.println("SQLState : " + e.getSQLState());
        System.err.println("SQLCode : " + e.getErrorCode());
        e = e.getNextException();
        System.err.println();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to insert data and select the table after inserted. But it returns the error message "no results were returned by the query"

I did use `executeUpdate` and `executeQuery` for different SQL statement.

Any suggestion for that?

BTW, the insert action is running successful.
The only thing I want is just to solve out the error and execute the select statement print out the table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resultStmt hasn't been initialized. Add

```
resultStmt = con.createStatement();
```

before

```
rs = resultStmt.executeQuery(SQLStatement);
```

Comment: ya..problem solved after i post it...i haven't clean and build project before i run the program.......so stupid..... :p  thanks for your reply..